# Inconsistent results with startAnimation in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to animate my imagebuttons by making them wobble when clicked.

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
       switch (v.getId()){
           case R.id.buttonStart:
               buttonStart.startAnimation(wobble);
               Intent i;
               i = new Intent(this, CityRendActivity.class);
               startActivity(i);
               break;
       }
}
```

When I click my Start button, it very slowly starts to wobble, but only appears to shake back and forth like 3 times, and a lot slower than I have defined in the xml file.   When I remove the lines that contain the intent code, the wobble works perfectly and the button shakes 5 times quickly (though now of course it doesn't load up my other activity).

So why would the code after the wobble animation effect how it's run?  Doesn't each line get resolved individually before proceeding?  I don't understand how loading up a different activity would effect the animation that I've set up.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Just a side note: switch to the honeycomb Animation api if you can. View animations are very old,  very inflexible and very  restrictive. The honeycomb animation api does everything view animations do, just a lot better and then some!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding animation listener for your animation and onAnimationEnd() start your Activity Intent.

```
    wobble.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

   @Override
   public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){}

   @Override
   public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){}

   @Override
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){
           startActivity(new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, CityRendActivity.class)); // if the code is in Fragment, then replace YourCurrentActivity.this by getActivity()
   }
});
```

Comment: I'm unsure where I would put this code in regards to the code I posted up top.

Comment: I tried to use your suggestion and am only getting errors for the Intent constructor

Comment: You have to place this code in your buttonStart onClick followed by buttonStart.startAnimation(wobble) . For errors in Intent Constructor, answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually In this code. animation and starting a new activity will execute at a same time. that will disturb the animation in between. so delay the starting of  activity with your animation time. so that animation will completed and then your Activity will start.hope this work for you.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

@Overide
void run(){
 startActivity(new Intent(this, CityRendActivity.class));

}
},time_ofanimation);
```

Comment: How would you incorporate this into the code I posted above?

Comment: **just add after the**  buttonStart.startAnimation(wobble);